# Алгоритм для нахождения определителя матрицы

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, есть ли какой-нибудь алгоритм для нахождения определителя матрицы? 
Мне нужно будет его на js перевести

Comment: интересно, причем тут С++?

Comment: ну я не знала в какой раздел написать)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [Третья ссылка в гугле](http://mathhelpplanet.com/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=22296&p=119033)
2. [Четвертая ссылка в гугле](http://loadj.ru/jmath/)

Comment: спасибо! то, что надо)

Comment: теперь этот вопрос первый в гугле ))